# which opengl version runs on every device?

Tags: opengl, opengl-es

Using [llvm](http://llvm.org) you can write a Programm which runs on PC, Mobile and since [WebAssembly](https://webassembly.org/) even in your Webbrowser. But for an Example Android uses Opengl-ES. Is there any opengl version which can be used on each of these platforms?

Comment: You probably want GL ES 2. It's mostly a subset of GL 3.2, which runs on PC. And WebGL seems to be similar to (I guess a subset of) GL ES 2.

Answer (score 0):

There is no single version of OpenGL that runs everywhere, but OpenGL ES 2.0 is pretty close to the lowest common denominator.

WebGL 1.0 is very similar to OpenGL ES 2.0. WebGL 2.0 is a subset of OpenGL ES 3.0, with various restrictions which are required for security.

On desktop systems, there is usually a way to create an OpenGL ES 2.0-compatible context and use the exact same API as on Android. Regular desktop OpenGL has a few incompatibilities with OpenGL ES, see for example this page:
https://www.khronos.org/webgl/wiki/WebGL_and_OpenGL_Differences

Mobile devices almost universally support OpenGL ES 2.0, and most flagship phones support OpenGL ES 3.2. The current distribution of support for OpenGL ES on Android phones is at the bottom of this page: https://developer.android.com/about/dashboards/